# What is the easyest way to use gems in a macruby application, in XCode?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, macruby

I need to include a rubygem in a simple macruby application i am creating in XCode. Using require 'rubygems' does not give an error, but the next line to require any other gems has a load error. I installed the gems using macgems. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error do you get? I'm not sure anyone will be able to help without a little more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The load error might be an indication that the gem doesn't work on Macruby. Post the error and someone might have more info on that gem or that error.

Did the gem actually install correctly? If it did install, does it work from the command line? Try creating a simple script that requires rubygems and your gem and run that on the command line outside of xcode and see if the problem is compatibility with that gem.

A while back in the 0.5 days I had this problem with a gem (miniexif iirc) that would install via macgems but not load or run. This might be a similar problem.